# Can you set attributes on Backbone.js Collections? If so, how?

Tags: backbone.js

I am just getting into backbone.js and I thought the best way to get into it is to actually build a todo list (yea...pretty original). Humor aside, I have searched google and the docs and stackoverflow of course, for a way to add an attribute to a collection. So, in my case a todo list is a collection of listitems. However a Todo List can have a title as according to my design, I want to be able to create multiple lists.

```
var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ListItem
});

//is this possible for collections?
var newTodoList = new TodoList({name: "My first list"});
```

Thanks a lot for the help! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Look at the signature of the `Collection` constructor:

> new Collection([models], [options])

So you could write like this:

```
var ListItem = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ListItem,
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        options || (options = {});
        if (options.title) {
            this.title = options.title;
        };
    }
})

var iPromise = new TodoList([], {
    title: 'NY Resolutions'
})

console.log(iPromise.title);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! That was the answer :)

Comment: You're welcome. But I thought a little bit more, and now I think my answer is not what you are looking for :). I suppose you want to be able to add listeners to the change event as well as you can do with `Models` attributes. But with the above mentionated approach you can't do it. Because there is nothing special about this `Collection` properties — it's just object properties and Backbone doesn't use it in any way. So I think it would be better to create a yet another Model contains your `TodoList`. I will give an example a bit later. Sorry if I confuse you.

Comment: keen to see the example :)